# What is AVHWAccel, and how can I use it?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I want to make use of hardware acceleration for decoding an h264 encoded MP4 file.

My computing environment:

```
Hardware: MacPro (2015 model)
Software: FFmpeg (installed by brew)
```

Here is the output of `FFmpeg` command:

```
$ffmpeg -hwaccels
Hardware acceleration methods:
vda 
videotoolbox
```

According to [this document](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro), there are two options for my environment, that is, `VDA` and `VideoToolBox`. I tried `VDA` in C++:

```
Codec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("h264_vda");
```

It kind of worked, but the output of the pixel format is `UYVY422` which I have trouble to deal with (any suggestion on how to render `UYVY422` in `C++`? The ideal format is `yuv420p`)

So I want to try `VideotoolBox`, but there is no such simple thing like (it may work in the case of encoding though)

```
Codec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("h264_videotoolbox");
```

It seems I should use `AVHWAccel`, but what is `AVHWAccel` and how to use it?

Part of My C++ code:

```
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++ ){
        if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
            pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec;
            video_stream = pFormatCtx->streams[i];
            if( pCodecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264 ){
                //pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
                pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("h264_vda");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // open codec
    if( pCodec ){
        if((ret=avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL)) < 0) {
        ....
```

Answer (score 4):

It's nothing to do with the decoder for which pix format to choose.

Your video pix format is `UYVY422`, so you got this format after you decode the frame.

Like the answer @halfelf mentioned, you can perform a swscale after you decode a frame, to convert the pix format to your ideal format `yuv420p`, then render it.

Meanwhile, if you are sure it's the format `UYVY422`, `SDL2` can handle the render directly for you.

In the example below, my format is `yuv420p`, and I use swscale to convert to `UYVY422` to render to `SDL2`

```
// prepare swscale context, AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422 is my destination pix format
SwsContext *swsCtx = sws_getContext(codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, codecCtx->pix_fmt,
                                    codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422,
                                    SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Renderer *render;
SDL_Texture *texture;

SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(codecCtx->width,
                            codecCtx->height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL, &window, &render);

texture = SDL_CreateTexture(render, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_UYVY, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
                            codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height);

// ......
// decode the frame 
// ......
AVFrame *frameUYVY = av_frame_alloc();
av_image_alloc(frameUYVY->data, frameUYVY->linesize, codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422, 32);

SDL_LockTexture(texture, NULL, (void **)frameUYVY->data, frameUYVY->linesize);

// convert the decoded frame to destination frameUYVY (yuv420p -> uyvy422)
sws_scale(swsCtx, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, frame->height,
                      frameUYVY->data, frameUYVY->linesize);

SDL_UnlockTexture(texture);

// performa render
SDL_RenderClear(render);
SDL_RenderCopy(render, texture, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(render);
```

In your example, if your pix format is `uyvy422`, you can skip the swscale part, and perform the render directly after decode from `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I got yuv420p using 'h264' decoder but uyvy422 using 'h264_vda' decoder for the same video file. If the pixel format is determined by the video file itself, does it mean that ffmpeg is changing the pixel format?

Comment: @shintaroid which pix_formats you mean?`AVCodec.pix_fmts` or `AVCodecContext.pix_fmt`? you should use the `pix_fmt` in `AVCodecContext`, it's detected when open input, ffmpeg usually won't change that for you. `AVCodec.pix_fmts` for `h264_vda` has many support pixel formats, including `uyvy422`. It's strange if it's like what you said. Could you show some code how you did that?

Comment: Thank you! I have added some sample code on the bottom of my question. In Xcode debug mode, when run at the last line of my sample code (that is, `if((ret=avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL)) < 0) {`), both `pCodecCtx` and `pCodec` show uyvy422 pix_fmt. However, when using `h264` decoder, both show yuv420p pix_fmt.

Comment: @shintaroid Did figure out what go wrong and what happened inside ffmpeg library. In my example, no matter what decoder used, the `pCodecCtx.pix_fmt` will keep the same with pixel format from input file. Nevertheless, back to your question, does it works if render directly to `SDL2`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using GLFW for rendering, so I'm not sure whether your code works or not. Do you think that it is possible for a decoder to output a different pixel format?

Comment: @shintaroid Yes, of course, you can set pixel format `codecCtx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422` to override the value found by demuxer if you know it better. I have tried a video with `yuv420p` pixel format and decode with `h264_vda` decoder, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Decoders won't choose which pixel format the output is, it is determined by the video itself. `swscale` lib is used to convert one pixel format to another.

```
auto sws_ctx = sws_getContext(src_width, src_height, AV_PIX_FMT_UYUV422, dst_width, dst_height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 0,0,0,0);
av_image_alloc(new_data, new_linesize, dst_width, dst_height, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, FRAME_ALIGN);
sws_scale(sws_ctx, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, src_height, new_data, new_linesize);
```

And there is no `h264_videotoolbox` decoder, only encoder. To list decoders/encoders available:

```
ffmpeg -encoders
ffmpeg -decoders
```

The decoder/encoder names is written in the source, for example, at the end of `libavcodec/vda_h264_dec.c` and `libavcodec/videotoolboxenc.c`.